# Accessing SVN from LAN

Tags: svn, lan

I am running a subversion service on my localhost, I want users on the LAN to be able to access this repository without being prompted for username and password. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to bother with config files and you're running Windows, take a look at [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). With it you're able to start fully functional SVN server in a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, give anonymous users the right to read and write.

This is the chapter that covers it in **the book**: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html